# R Can I use .rds files for my data in a package?

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to convert some code into a package. According to the documentation, only .RData files should be in the data directory, but I'd rather use .rds files because they don't retain the file name. There are times when I save with a different name than I want to use when reading in later. And I really only want to have one data set for file, so the ability of .RData files to store more is actually a negative.

So my question is why not allow .rds files in the package data directory? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hadley has some good documentation [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html).

Comment: The answer to my question seems to be that the only acceptable data files in /data are those saved with 'save', which means they are in the .RData format. The Hadley link that @r2evans points to says this. As does the section 1.1.6 that rawr points to.

Comment: Are there some specific reasons why using RData instead of RDS? as you say @JerryN RDS are very handy to import data in script without any a priori knowledge on the object name.  Just curious to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only acceptable data files in `/data` are those saved with 'save', which means they are in the .RData format. [Hadley's link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html), which @r2evans points to, says this. As does [section 1.1.6](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages), which @rawr points to.

Answer (score 2):

Old question - but you can. It is a two step process.

1. save your data as `.rds` file
2. create an R file in the data directory which loads the rds data.

I am doing this as followed:

```
rdsFile <- paste0(schemeName, "_example.rds")
saveRDS(
      dmdScheme_example,
      file = here::here( "data", rdsFile )
    )
cat(
      paste0(schemeName, "_example <- readRDS(\"./", rdsFile, "\")"),
      file = here::here( "data", paste0(schemeName, "_example.R") )
    )
```

Comment: One problem - CRAN does not like it. So it works for internal packages, but not CRAN. I posted a follow-up question there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293910/create-r-data-with-a-dynamic-variable-name-from-function-for-package.\